# laravel mail sending is not taken database email for from field

Tags: laravel

```
$user_details=DB::table('table_users')
                     ->select('table_users.*')
                     ->where('id', $user_id)
                     ->first();

         \Mail::send('Invoice', array(
                            'name' => $user_details->name,
                            'email' => $user_details->email,
                            'subject' =>'Order is placed',
                        ), function($message) use ($req){
                            $message->from($user_details->email);
                            $message->to('xyz@gmail.com', 'Admin')->subject('Order is Placed');
                        });
```

I am sending mail in laravel 5.7. My from email id in `$user_details->email` but it can not get in `$message->from($user_details->email)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using annoymous function as the callback you need to pass the email in use() function as below:

```
use ($user_details){
```

you're not using $req neither it's defined anywhere you shared your code here so i think get rid of that if not needed.